# Getting a TcpOutboundGateway Timeout Exception

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I am getting message timeout exception for a few cases, I am able to see the response sent from TCP server, but not captured on the app side which is throwing the timeout exception, I am suspecting the socket connection is being closed by the TCP server.

What could be the solution here?

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableIntegration
    @Slf4j
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class TcpClientConfig implements ApplicationEventPublisherAware {

    private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;


    @Bean(name = "visaConnectionFactory")
    public AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactoryVisa() {
        ISOConnectionProperties visa = applicationProperties.getIsoServers().getVisa();
        TcpNioClientConnectionFactory tcpNioClientConnectionFactory =
                new TcpNioClientConnectionFactory("host", port);
        tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setUsingDirectBuffers(true);
        tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setApplicationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher);
        tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setDeserializer(new ByteArrayCrLfSerializer());
        return new CachingClientConnectionFactory(tcpNioClientConnectionFactory, 50);
    }

    @Bean(name = "mastercardConnectionFactory")
    public AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactoryMastercard() {
        ISOConnectionProperties mastercard = applicationProperties.getIsoServers().getMastercard();
        TcpNioClientConnectionFactory tcpNioClientConnectionFactory =
                new TcpNioClientConnectionFactory("host", port);
        tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setUsingDirectBuffers(true);
                tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setDeserializer(new ByteArrayCrLfSerializer());
tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setApplicationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher);
        return new CachingClientConnectionFactory(tcpNioClientConnectionFactory, 50);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel outboundChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }


    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "router.channel")
    public HeaderValueRouter consumeRouterMessage() {
        HeaderValueRouter router = new HeaderValueRouter("cardType");
        router.setChannelMapping("V", "outboundChannelVisa");
        router.setChannelMapping("M", "outboundChannelMastercard");
        return router;

    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outboundChannelVisa")
    public MessageHandler outboundGatewayVisa(
            @Qualifier("visaConnectionFactory") AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory) {
        TcpOutboundGateway tcpOutboundGateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
        tcpOutboundGateway.setConnectionFactory(clientConnectionFactory);
        tcpOutboundGateway.setRequestTimeout(5_000);
        return tcpOutboundGateway;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outboundChannelMastercard")
    public MessageHandler outboundGatewayMc(
            @Qualifier("mastercardConnectionFactory") AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory) {
        TcpOutboundGateway tcpOutboundGateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
        tcpOutboundGateway.setConnectionFactory(clientConnectionFactory);
        tcpOutboundGateway.setRequestTimeout(5_000);
        tcpOutboundGateway.setUnsolicitedMessageChannelName("unsolicited");
        return tcpOutboundGateway;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "unsolicited")
    public void handleUnsolicited(String in) {
        log.debug("Unsolicited response:{}", in);
    }

}



    @MessagingGateway
    public interface TcpClientGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "router.channel")
    byte[] send(Message<byte[]> message);

}
```

Comment: You probably need to be sure that messages delimiter is supplied properly. That is `(de)serializer` option of the `AbstractClientConnectionFactory`. And server side sends a proper delimiter with its responses. See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-codecs

Comment: @ArtemBilan I have mentioned the gateway with byte[], Is the deserializer still required?

Comment: Well, see that doc. There is indeed a default one is `\r\n`. So, be sure that your client config matches with whatever server expects and produces.

Comment: @ArtemBilan, I am seeing this message too after capturing the response,
 Cannot correlate response - no pending reply for Cached:127.0.0.1:6001:64493:d7c6cf4e-d305-42ac-815c-49725ba9bee7,
 Added a deserializer now, still seeing this correlated response, Is this fine?                          The code is updated.

Comment: `this.pendingReplies.get(connectionId)` returns `null`  for you. Apparently your server sends several reply messages to your request. This is not what such a gateway is designed for. There could be only one request and reply for it.